# For signature $s= \{ f\}, n_f=1$, show that if for structures $M, N$, $f^N, f^M$ have only one orbit, of infinite order, then $M,N$ are isomorphic

Tags: model-theory

For signature $s= \{ f\}, n_f=1$, show that if for structures $M, N$, $f^N, f^M$ have only one orbit, of infinite order, then $M,N$ are isomorphic.

So we know that for some $m \in M$, the set $\{f^k(m): k \in \mathbb Z \}$ is infinite, and we know that for some $n \in N$, the set $\{f^k(n): k \in \mathbb Z \}$ is infinite (the first $f$ is $f^M$, the second one is $f^N$).

My initial guess is that $\alpha ((f^M)^k(m))=(f^N)^k(n)$ will suffice as an isomorphism. However I cant really think of a way to show it's surjective.

Note: The question defines the order of $a \in M$ as the set $\{f^k(a): k\in \mathbb Z \}$, and when $k \lt 0, f^k(a)=(f^{-1}\circ f^{-1}\circ \cdots \circ f^{-1})(a)$, $k$ times.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you define the orbit of an object $a$ as the set of $f^{(k)}(a)$ where $k$ ranges over the integers? That's sort of OK in certain contexts, but I would have expected the $k$ to range over the non-negative integers.

Comment: It is also over the negative and non-negative integers. Will edit.

Comment: Does the question also specify that $f$ is injective? (What _else_ does the problem say that you're not telling us?)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Well, the first thing OP "didn't tell us" was which way to read an ambiguous, poorly written statement. I suspect the first revision is the problem as stated. There are always going to be conventions/assumptions that appear earlier in the text which an inexperienced mathematician will assume to be standard. The invertibility of a given interpretation of $f$ seems to be one of those, albeit a very odd convention!

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld Fair enough. One has to wonder whether one of those things suffices to make the problem other than obviously wrong...

Comment: It becomes obviously right, as the guess the OP made would be a valid isomorphism.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld ??? I'm missing something. It looks to me as though the OP didn't even _define_ $\alpha(x)$ for $x$ not in that famous infinite orbit. What's the problem with the thing I posted that I thought was a counterexample?

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld OH! I missed the comma! Read "one orbit, of infinite order" as "one orbit of infinite order". Never mind, sorry.

Comment: If we build into orbit the existence of the inverse, then there is an  isomorphism between $M$ and the integers under successor.

Comment: I think $k$ should be non-negative, because nothing assures you, that $f^\mathcal{M}$ has an inverse. 

For surjectivity, since $\mathcal{N}$ has only one orbit $\mathcal{N}=\{(f^\mathcal{N})^k(n_0) |k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ for some $n_0\in\mathcal{N}$. So if $n\in\mathcal{N}$, $n=(f^\mathcal{N})^k(n_0)$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. And then

$\alpha((f^\mathcal{M})^k(m_0))=(f^\mathcal{N})^k(n_0)=n$

Comment: Is this question supposed to be understood as, the universe of $M$ is the orbit of some $m\in{M}$? It is vague, and the other interpretations don't make much sense

1) there is exactly one $m\in{M}$ s.t. the orbit of $m$ is infinite: But then, $m$ and $f(m)$ have different infinite orbits. So the statement is vacuously true 

2) There is an infinite orbit, s.t. any other infinite orbit is a contained in that particular one, in which case this is false. Take $\omega$ with $f$ interpreted as the successor and the same set with $f(0)=0$ and $f$ as the succesor otherwise. These are non-isomorphic.